# How to change DataContext of a ContextMenu item?

Tags: xaml, contextmenu, datacontext

In my XAML, I have a read-only ListView and on right click of a listView item I want to provide a click-option which will update the property of an object and eventually update 'My Name' column of the list view.

Let's say my listView is in Primary.Xaml. DataContext of this xaml is ObjectInfo. 
Xaml has a listView and a ContextMenu like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lview" SelectedIndex="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=gridItems, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=gridItems, Path=ActualHeight}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle}">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="mitem" Click="mitem_Click" >
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="My Name"/>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id#" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Number#" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" />                 
                    <GridViewColumn Header="My Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MyName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

So, my listView's DataContext is ObjectInfo which has MyName as a read-only property.

```
public string MyName { get; private set; }
```

I'm loading the property like this:

```
MyName = dr.GetString("DifferentObject" + "MyName");
```

Which means I have to update the property on "DifferentObject" object and listen the change from Primary.Xaml.

This is the property from "DifferentObject" I want to update and bind into my ContextMenu.

```
private static readonly PropertyInfo<bool> IsMyNameProperty = RegisterValueProperty<bool>(x => x.IsMyName);
    public bool IsMyName
    {
        get { return GetProperty(IsMyNameProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(IsMyNameProperty, value);

            if (value)
            {
                SetProperty(MyNameIdProperty, UserId);
                SetProperty(MyNameProperty, Name);
            }
            else
            {
                SetProperty(MyNameIdProperty, 0);
                SetProperty(MyNameProperty, string.Empty);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Code behind of my xaml, I'm planning to do all the logic and datacontext manipulation:

```
private void mitem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = lview.SelectedItem as ObjectInfo;

        var Name = GetInfo().Name;

        if (selectedItem.MyName != Name)
        {
            var item = lview.DataContext as DifferentObject; //I have item as null

            //after I get item, I will be able to assign true to IsMyName
        }
    }
```

So! My question is, how do I have a different DataContext for my ContextMenu?

Comment: Did anyone have chance to take a look at this?